# Convenience init without arguments in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm trying to make a class like this:

```
class Brick2 : SKShapeNode {

    override convenience init() {       
        self.init(rectOf: CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/5, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/5), cornerRadius: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/20)
    }

}
```

The code compiles but when I launch the app in the simulator it crashes.

The thing is that with this other class it works:

```
class Sidebar : SKShapeNode {

    convenience init(rectOf: CGSize, cornerRadius: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) {                
         self.init(rectOf: rectOf, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)        
         self.position = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, y : y)
    }
}
```

If I don't override the init using one with arguments it works, but no overriding it.

I want to instantiate the class Brick2 without passing any argument, because all the bricks will have the same size.

The error in Xcode is:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee4f8fff8)

Comment: "it crashes." well, what's the crash log say, in particular?

Comment: Your init without params doesn't set position.  If that's an optional and you later use it, you'd crash.

Comment: Exactly what init are you trying to override?

Comment: I don't think you want to `override` the init. If I understand your intent correctly you want to say something like `let brick = Brick2()` and have your custom init method execute. Your current code is overriding the init on the `SKShapeNode` class which I don't think is your intent.

Comment: But SKShapeNode doesn't have an init() method from what I see so it is SKNode.init() that is being overridden, ins't that the issue here?

Comment: Where does the crash occur? In the init() or later, when you call some method on the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the `init()` that you are trying to override does not belong to **SKShapeNode**, or its superclass **SKNode**, or its superclass **UIResponder**; but it's overriding the root-class **NSObject**'s `init()`.

Practically, you cannot override a designated initializer (`init()`), and use a convenience initializer (`init(rect:cornerRadius:)`) to initialize an object.

To serve the purpose of what you are trying to achieve, I would suggest this:

```
class Brick2: SKShapeNode {

    // Make init() inaccessible to other classes, to prevent the accidental usage of the same,
    // instead of the expected instance() method call.
    private override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    class func instance() -> Brick2 {
        return Brick2(rectOf: CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 5,
                                     height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 5),
                      cornerRadius: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 20)
    }
}
```

Then, you can initialize your **Brick2** instance using:

```
let brick = Brick2.instance()
```